# Multiple Show Hide Divs with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I can get the first div to hide and second to show, but how would I then get the 2nd div to hide and 3rd div to show after some time?

CSS...

```
 #showhide2, #showhide3{ display : none; }
```

Script...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showhide1").delay(10000).hide(0, function() {
        $("#showhide2").show();
    });

});
</script>
```

Body...

```
<div id="showhide1">
<p>show 1</p>
</div>

<div id="showhide2">
<p >show - 2</p>
</div>

<div id="showhide3">
<p>show 3</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3fF4s/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way is using setTimeout

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showhide1").delay(1000).hide(0, function() {
        $("#showhide2").show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#showhide2").hide();
            $("#showhide3").show();
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3fF4s/7/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way you showed the second div

http://jsfiddle.net/3fF4s/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showhide1").delay(5000).hide(0, function() {
        $("#showhide2").show(function(){
            $(this).delay(5000).hide(0, function(){
                $('#showhide3').show();
            });
        });
    });
});
```